# How can I optimise the ordinal encoding of a 2D array of strings in Python?

Tags: python, c, numpy, optimization, encoding

I have a Pandas series that holds an array of strings per row:

```
0                                           []
1                                           []
2                                           []
3                                           []
4         [0007969760, 0007910220, 0007910309]
                          ...                 
243223                                      []
243224                            [0009403370]
243225                [0009403370, 0007190939]
243226                                      []
243227                                      []
Name: Item History, Length: 243228, dtype: object
```

My goal is to do some straightforward Ordinal Encoding here, but as efficiently (in terms of both time and memory) as possible, with the following caveats:

1. Empty lists need to have an integer denoting "Empty list" inserted that is also unique. (for example if there are 100 unique strings, empty lists might be encoded as `[101]`).
2. The encoding must be saved somehow such that I can identically encode other lists in the future
3. Where those future lists contain a string that is not present in the initial input data, it must encode its own separate integer to denote "Never seen that before mate".

The obvious question is "Why are you not just using OrdinalEncoder from sklearn". Well, apart from not having an unknown item handler, it's also actually horrendously slow to apply rowwise in this fashion (we'd have to fit it on a combined single array of all the distinct strings, then use `Series.apply(lambda x: oe.transform(x))` to transform each row), because it has to do some dict-comprehension to build the mapping table *for each row* and that takes time. Not very much time *per call*, only about 0.01 seconds, but that's still far too slow for the amount of data that I have.

One solution is to take that dict comprehension out of the each-row part, and build a mapping table before looping over the rows, as in this function:

```
def encode_labels(X, table, noHistory, unknownItem):

    res = np.empty(len(X), dtype=np.ndarray)

    for i in range(len(X)):
        if len(X[i]) == 0:
            res[i] = np.array([noHistory])
        else:
            res[i] = np.empty(len(X[i]), dtype=np.ndarray)
            for j in range(len(X[i])):
                try:
                    res[i][j] = table[X[i][j]]
                except KeyError:
                    res[i][j] = unknownItem

    return res
```

That's significantly better than row-wise `.apply()` but still not the fastest piece of code. I can cythonize it and do a bunch of other optimisations to get some more speedup, but it's not orders-of-magnitude better:

```
%%cython

cimport numpy as cnp
import numpy as np
from cpython cimport array
import array

cpdef list encode_labels_cy(cnp.ndarray X, dict table, int noHistory, int unknownItem, array.array rowLengths):

    cdef int[:] crc = rowLengths

    cdef list flattenedX = []    
    cdef Py_ssize_t i, j
    cdef list row = []

    for row in X:
        if len(row)==0:
            flattenedX.append('ZZ')
        else:
            flattenedX.extend(row)

    cdef Py_ssize_t lenX = len(flattenedX)

    cdef array.array res = array.array('i', [0]*lenX)
    cdef int[:] cres = res

    i=0
    while i < lenX:
        try:
            cres[i] = table[flattenedX[i]]
        except KeyError:
            cres[i] = unknownItem
        i += 1

    cdef list pyres = []
    cdef Py_ssize_t s = 0

    for k in crc:
        pyres.append(res[s:s+k])
        s+= k

    return pyres
```

```
# classes is a dict of {string:int} mappings. noHistory and unknownItem are ints encoding those values

%timeit encode_labels(X.values, classes, noHistory, unknownItem)
%timeit encode_labels_cy(X.values, classes, noHistory, unknownItem, array.array('i', [1 if x == 0 else x for x in [len(j) for j in X]]))

50.4 ms ± 2.76 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
11.2 ms ± 1.11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

(that's for a 5000 row sample, not the whole dataset).

**UPDATE:** I managed to get an implementation working in ctypes and that *is* faster than both the row-wise .apply() and my original native python, but it's still slower than Cython (which really ought not be the case in my mind!)

So; how can I make this faster? and ideally keep memory usage as low as possible at the same time? *This need not be pure python*. If you can make it zippy in Cython or ctypes or something, that's great. This code will form part of the preprocessing for a neural net so there's also some GPUs sitting around waiting for data at this point; if you can make this utilise those then all the better. Multiprocessing might also be an option that I haven't managed to explore yet, but the problem there is that it requires a copy of the string:int mapping table per process, which is a) slow to generate and b) uses lots of memory.

**EDIT**:

Forgot to provide some data. You can run the following to get an input dataset that's in similar format to mine:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

X = pd.Series([[a[np.random.randint(0, 26)] for i in range(np.random.randint(0, 10))] for j in range(5000)])

classes = dict(zip(a, np.arange(0, 26)))
unknownItem = 26
noHistory = 27
```

Only 5000 rows, but that should be enough to accurately determine which method is faster.

Comment: The ctypes-based version is not very efficient as parameters are recomputed for each iteration. You can put `(ct.c_wchar_p*len(a))(*a)` in a temporary variable before the loop as `a` is constant. The same thing apply for other constant parameters. Moreover, you can use `res.extend(cResult)` which is faster. You can also pre-allocate `cResult` to the maximum size of all rows to avoid ctype re-allocations and then use `res.extend(cResult[:len(row)])`. This is 4 times faster on my machine. But `*row` is still a problem. It is possible to change the input data structure to make it more efficient?

Comment: @JérômeRichard sure, go nuts. As long as the memory doesn't balloon into something unreasonable I'm happy to contemplate pretty much any rejigging. 4x faster still makes it slower than the pure Python/Cython version, right? I'm trying to work through a linked list implementation to deal with the whole of the input at once instead of RBAR.

Comment: On my machine, the initial python version take 27ms, an optimized python version 20ms, the initial ctype version 5.65ms, the optimized ctype version 1.45. The cython version does not build (since the type of X is invalid). So it might be worth testing this on your machine. By the way the C code could be also improved by using dichotomy on sorted keys or hashing rather than iterating over all keys (useful if you have a lot of keys).

Comment: @JérômeRichard That's strange, my initial ctype version there is significantly slower than the initial Python version. I wonder why there'd be such a difference

Comment: @JérômeRichard oh, for the Cython one just pass X.values

Comment: Produce `classes, noHistory, unknownItem` for the minimal sample data?

Comment: @Divakar; they're in there now.

Comment: @DanScally So to understand this correctly, your benchmarks only involve transforming the data, not building the table? So you aim only for efficiency w.r.t. applying the transformation (and don't mind about performance when fitting the encoder)?

Comment: @a_guest I wouldn't say I _don't mind_, in that if you some how manage to make the fitting step take as much time as the transformation does then that's not going to be acceptable, but it's such a negligible part of the operation (5 microseconds in that sample data) that it's probably not worth spending time to optimise that part.

Comment: In your actual setup, would the input strings always represent positive numbers being represented as strings?

Comment: @Divakar yes, but (I think I see where you're doing here) note that they aren't necessarily consecutive and don't start at 0, so a straight conversion of the data type to Integer will not suffice because the elements further down the pipeline expect the data to be Ordinal Encoded in the normal fashion (I.E. in the range [0, n) where n is the number of distinct values in the encoded list). EDIT: Oh I'm wrong anyway, some of them have letters in. TIL.

Comment: @DanScally Can you provide additional information on the data types that you expect to come out of the transformation? The original input data is a `pd.Series` and it's elements are of type `list` but in your `encode_labels` you return a `ndarray` which contains `ndarray`s as elements. Would a list of list also suffice for example? Or it doesn't matter as long as it's iterable?

Comment: @a_guest Any form of 2D array is fine. I think I found ndarrays to be faster when I started trying to optimise, which is why I started using them.

Comment: @DanScally Is the maximum number of strings per row bound from above or can it be anything?

Comment: @a_guest at this point it is unlimited - which is one of the reasons a ctypes implementation is annoying. I resorted to a linked list, which is _stonkingly_ fast in comparison to Python, but the necessarily pythonic pre-processing ruined the gains I made with that attempt.

Comment: @DanScally Also I can't reproduce your timings using the example data, namely `encode_labels` takes 900 ms while the Cython `encode_labels_cy` takes only 7.56 ms, i.e. two orders of magnitude faster (not what you report though). Did you benchmark your solutions also on the example data or just on the real data (does it make a difference)? Also in the Cython one, where do you deal with unknown elements?

Comment: @a_guest started chat, realised it wasn't live, immediately gave up. Some difference in benchmarks does not surprise me, although the fact that it's _so_ different is a bit odd I agree, but not sure what to say about that. The benchmarks are for the test data only; the real dataset is well over a million rows and takes about an hour. I accidentally left the "doesn't encode unknown elements" bug in the Cython code...sorry!! I've fixed it now, it's just a try/except and does not significantly change the speed of that solution (for me at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one based on [`NumPy's searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
k,v = classes.keys(),classes.values()
k,v = np.array(list(k)),np.array(list(v))

cl = np.concatenate(s)

sidx = k.argsort()
idx = np.searchsorted(k,cl, sorter=sidx)
out_of_bounds_mask = idx==len(k)

idx[out_of_bounds_mask] = 0
ssidx = sidx[idx]
invalidmask = k[ssidx] != cl
out_of_bounds_mask |= invalidmask

vals = v[ssidx]
vals[out_of_bounds_mask] = unknownItem

lens = list(map(len,s))
E = [noHistory] # use np.array() if you need outputs for empty entries as arrays
out = []
start = 0
for l in lens:
    if l==0:
        out.append(E)
    else:
        out.append(vals[start:start+l])
        start += l
```

Another way is basically `encode_labels` from posted question but optimized with less accesses to inputs and avoiding the try-catch -

```
def encode_labels2(X, table, noHistory, unknownItem):
    L0 = len(X)
    res = [[noHistory]]*L0
    for i in range(L0):
        L = len(X[i])
        if L != 0:
            res_i = [unknownItem]*L
            for j in range(L):
                Xij = X[i][j]
                if Xij in table:
                    res_i[j] = table[Xij]
            res[i] = res_i
    return res
```

Then, we can introduce numba's jit compilation. So, the changes would be -

```
from numba import jit

@jit
def encode_labels2(X, table, noHistory, unknownItem):
# .. function stays the same
```

There would be few warnings, which it seems to be because we are working with lists and not arrays. Those could be ignored.

Comment: Thanks, that runs, but it's kicking in at about 100ms compared to the 6-7ms of the current best effort.

Comment: about 11ms; so significantly better but still slightly slower than the existing Cython version. Quite fast for pure python though!

Comment: @DanScally And then numba's additions (edits) should help further.

Comment: Ah sorry I missed the edit. The numba  version **is** faster by a significant way...which annoys me because I swear I tried it previously and concluded it was worse than Cython in this specific case!! But thanks; that's the fastest solution to date.

Comment: @DanScally What's the runtime with the numba one?

Comment: about 750 microseconds, but actually looking again just adding the decorator also changes the output; possibly this is why I discounted using numba originally

Comment: @DanScally Are you saying the output with numba is not what you expect it to be?

Comment: @DanScally The output values are all correct for me. On the format side, the output is a list of lists. Is that what's putting it off for you? If so, are you looking to get an array of arrays or list of arrays or array of lists?

Comment: Format is fine as long as it's a 2D iterable, it's the actual values that were different...but it turns out to be my machine :S - I don't know what the heck is happening on my machine but the output is completely different using the numba version here compared to running it in google colab or databricks. So, sorry - disregard - it's some problem with my install or something.

Comment: thanks again; fastest by a way and the bounty period is up, so you get the tick :)

Answer (score 1):

With the following Cython function I get a speed-up factor of about 5. It uses a temporary list for row-wise copies of relevant data which should be initialized big enough so that it can hold each row's data (i.e. if an upper bound for the maximum number of elements per row is known, use that one, otherwise use a heuristic value that keeps the number of necessary resizes to a minimum).

```
cpdef list encode_labels_cy_2(cnp.ndarray X, dict table, int noHistory, int unknownItem):

    cdef Py_ssize_t i, n
    cdef list result = []
    cdef list tmp = [noHistory] * 10  # initialize big enough so that it's likely to fit all elements of a row

    for row in X:
        n = len(row)
        while len(tmp) < n:  # if too small, resize
            tmp.append(noHistory)
        if n > 0:
            i = 0
            while i < n:
                tmp[i] = table.get(row[i], unknownItem)
                i += 1
        else:
            tmp[0] = noHistory
            i = 1
        result.append(tmp[:i])

    return result
```

If the number of elements per row varies strongly and no good estimate can be made up-start you can also resize the `tmp` list by over-allocating similar to [CPython's list growth pattern](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/472fc843ca816d65c12f9508ac762ca492165c45/Objects/listobject.c#L62).

Comment: I get the same 5x speedup over the existing cython; thank you! The number of elements regrettably does vary strongly, I'll test both calculating the max (which is known but likely to be a slightly expensive op itself) and the over-allocation and see what that looks like.

Comment: @DanScally First calculating the max over the whole data will be very expensive, this should be avoided. Instead just use any large number. I expect the max. length of a row to be significantly smaller than the length of the data frame, so even if you choose factor 10 or 100 larger than the training data max. it won't affect memory in a noticeable way. This is an important point though, so it might help to analyze the length distribution of the training data. Do you have any numbers for that (e.g. mean, std, max, a histogram, etc)?